# Google Cloud SQL goes to sleep after some idle time?

Tags: sails.js, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying Sails.JS with Google Cloud SQL, all seem to work fine, except that after some idle period, the DB seems to go to sleep, timing out on the first request after a long period of time.

Anyone else encountered this, and is there any known solution?

Comment: Sails.JS returns on the first 2 requests - ERROR:ETIMEDOUT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to minimize the amount you are charged for instances on per use billing plans, by default your instance becomes passive if it is not accessed for 15 minutes. The next time it is accessed there will be a short delay while it is activated. You can change this behavior by configuring the activation policy of the instance in the console.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#sometimes_slow

Comment: I see, makes sense. So just switching to "Package" plan will do the trick?

Comment: Nah, didn't help. So the only way is to change the Activation via gcutil? Package plan kind-of not making sense then.

Comment: Switching to package plan should help - that means your instance goes to sleep after 12 hours of inactivity instead of 15 minutes. Did you experience something different? Activation policy is useful if you want exact control over the instance uptime.

Comment: From my testing, the package plan had exactly same issue - the instance went offline after 15 minute of not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on the Activation Policy settings per the first answer given.  Switching between "Per Use" and "Package Plan" are primarily billing settings.  Switch your Activation Policy to "Always On" if you want to prevent the database from throttling down to idle.